# EMR and Exception from container-launch

Tags: hadoop, containers, amazon-emr

I am new to EMR and whenever I run a job I get this error in syslog:

`2014-05-27 03:59:57,220 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1401143947501_0009 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1401143947501_0009 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1401143947501_0009_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)`

I have no idea what this means and what I should look into. I have looked around quite a bit and there seems to be lot of different opinions. Some have suggested removing yarn.application.classpath from yarn-site.xml and/or changing yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb in the same file. But, nothing has worked so far. I feel like I am shooting in the dark. If someone can point me what I should look for, then it will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance